# shared variable in map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, uniqueidentifier

I need a variable that shared between reduce tasks and each of reduce tasks can read and write on it atomically.
The reason that I need such a variable is to give a unique identifier to each files that created by reduce task (number of files which created by reduce tasks is not deterministic).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding ZooKeeper is specially built to maintain atomic access to the cluster wide variables.

Comment: I search for such variables but can't find anything.

Comment: Zookeeper is a generic facitlity to create and update cluster wide data structures. http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html you should call setData and getData with your own path, which means "name" of the variable

Comment: I hope you do realize that doing something like this effectively breaks the scalability of your application. A centralized atomic variable requires locking and locking breaks horizontal scalability. Perhaps in your case that's ok but in general it's a "Bad idea".

Comment: Sure, that global variable of any kind is a potential bottleneck. But there are cases when they can not be avoided. They should not be used for massive communication. But in this particular case - it was a question how to track some global variable - and it is for what ZooKeeper specifically built.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `FileSystem.createNewFile()`.

Have a look here:

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#createNewFile%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29

Answer (score 0):

All the outout files produced by the reducers already have unique names part-r-00001 and such.
There is a partition number you can read in case you need that number from your code.

Centralized counters that must be guaranteed unique break a lot of the scalability of Hadoop.

So if you need something different then I would use something like a Sha1 of the task id of the reducer to get something that is unique over multiple jobs.

Comment: Your idea doesn't work properly in my case because I don't want to run tasks just one time, I mean tasks should run every day and all the files has been created at different times should have different name

Comment: Then simply us the ID of the reducer task. That's unique for this purpose. And if don't like the name you can always use the SHA1 of that string as your number.